# wp_head function outputs after <head>

Tags: wp-head

I have a function in my functions file where i output Google Analytics code.

```
    function mytheme_trackingcode(){
    $mytheme_option = mytheme_get_global_options();
    $tracking_code = $mytheme_option['tracking_code_head'];
    if($tracking_code){
        echo '$tracking_code';
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'mytheme_trackingcode');
```

The problem is that the output comes right after the  tag. I'm not sure what the problem is? wp_head is placed last in head-section.

Comment: Can you post the portion of the code that does `wp_head()`?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand your question. wp_head is a core WordPress action.

Comment: Yes, a core action executed by [`wp_head()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head), which must be called at the correct time by your theme...typically in `header.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'$tracking_code'` ist just a string. It closes `<head>` automatically. So, no, it doesn’t come after the `head`, you just failed to use **source view**. Firebug and similar tools show just the rendered DOM, that’s not good enough.

Fix: `echo $tracking_code;`.

Comment: I removed the ' and tried again, but i discovered a new problem, WordPress strips the <script> tags.

Comment: @andeersg No, it doesn’t. I’m 100% sure.

Comment: I checked again and tried with the "esc_js" function when i save the code. Then the script tags was included, but the code gets " around the code and it is outputed after body tag.

Comment: Then your _save_ function is wrong, not the output.

Comment: I'm googling alot now, but can anyone point me in the direction of the function recommended for saving inline-javascript and outputing it?

Comment: [Ask a new question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) ;)